# How do I use the user desired input in Python to open a website?

Tags: python

I am building a virtual assistant in Python and I want to add a feature where the user says the name of the website and the VA will open that website in the browser. I know the code for opening the web browser is:
`webbrowser.open()`

how can I use the user desired input in this if the input is being stored in `new_input`?

Comment: `webbrowser.open(new_input)`?

Comment: then how will I add the ".com"?

Comment: It's just a string.  You modify it like you would any other string.

Comment: Okay, let me try to explain it better:

Let's say the user says "stackoverflow". How will I add the ".com" into the ```webbrowser.open()```?

Comment: Again, it's a string. Do you know how to work with strings? That's a basic thing

Comment: Okay I get it now. That was really dumb from me. Thanks tho

Comment: Or you could use a dictionary of keywords `url = {"stackoverflow": https://stackoverflow.com}[new_input]; webrowser.open(url)`